# Is this subspace dense in $L^{2}(\Omega,\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $X=L^{2}(\Omega,\mu)$ be the complex Hilbert space of square-integrable complex measurable functions on $\Omega$. (Each $f \in L^{2}$ is an equivalence class of measurable functions which are equal a.e. $[d\mu]$.)

If $f$ is a measurable function on $\Omega$, define $M_{f}$ to be the linear subspace of $X$ consisting of all $g \in L^{2}(\Omega,\mu)$ such that $fg\in L^{2}(\Omega,\mu)$.

Prove or disprove: $M_{f}$ is dense in $X$ for every real measurable $f$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I think I have the issue resolved, but I wanted to see what clever solution people here would find. Plus I don't find that this question has been posted before. Is that inappropriate?

Comment: Well, this is a very standard exercise (often proved as part of the spectral theorem).  So I think it's not unreasonable to apply the [usual standard for homework-type questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: Bah, thanks for the correction, my mistake. You get that they're in $L^1$, not $L^2$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Oh, okay. I've been out of classes for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: By replacing $f$ with a related function, show that it suffices to consider $f \ge 1$.

Hint 2: Try to show $M_f^\perp = 0$.

Hint 3: Suppose $h \in M_f^\perp$; try to show $\|h\|^2 = 0$.  Think about multiplying by $f/f$.

Comment: If $h\perp M_{f}$, then $h/(1+|f|)\in M_{f} \implies h/(1+|f|)\perp h\implies h=0\;\; a.e.$ So that was along the same line of thinking.